# pyinstaller not recognised, even though it is installed

Tags: python, pyinstaller, command-prompt, windows-11

I have pip installed pyinstaller, but when trying to build my file to an exe it says that it can't recognise pyinstaller in the command line. I am using command prompt on windows 11, for python 3
[picture of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpIU2.jpg)

Thanks in advance for the help!

I tried to use pyinstaller to turn a .py into a .exe, but it couldn't find the pyinstaller command.

Edit: thanks to John Gordon in the comments: I had not edited the PATH variable

Comment: Apparently you did not modify your `PATH` environment variable to include the directory where the pyinstaller program lives.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Do a google search for "windows path variable", I'm sure you'll find lots of examples.

Comment: I mean how do I find the pyinstaller directory, I have modified the PATH before

Comment: `pip show pyinstaller` would probably list the directory where it's installed.

Comment: Note that while the duplicate I linked was asked by someone on MacOS, it has both Linux and Windows answers added as well.

Answer (score 0):

Open Your CMD and type this Command `python -m pip install pyinstaller`
and then after installing run `pyinstaller --version` to check if it is installed or not in your system.

Comment: It just says access denied, do I have to run with admin?

Comment: yes just run with admin access.